# Traverse Mongoose Array from the back, with SKIP

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Is there a way to traverse query results in MongoDB / Mongoose from the back of the array?

I have a Story schema with messages an array element in the schema.

I can do

```
    Story.findById(story_id, { messages: { $slice: -limit  } } )
```

OR

```
       .where('messages').slice(-limit)
```

to get *limit* elements from the end of the array.  However, what I want to do is to skip N elements (from the end) and get *limit* elements.  i.e. traverse the entire array *limit* at a time.

I tried using skip() as well passing an array to slice()  (i.e. slice([skip, limit]), however it seems to be looking for a positive value for skip (i.e. position from beginning of the array, rather than from the end).

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

What I need is *limit* elements from *skip* away from the *end* of the array.

Comment: Ask yourself this question. "Why do you *think* you need to process from the last element in the array?" Possibly since that is the most recent. In which case the solution generally is to **store** your array content so the most recent item is the "first" element. There are a couple of ways to go about that.

Comment: Thanks Neil.  I did consider storing the array in opposite order with the most recent item first, but it seems that Mongo does not have a straightforward way of doing that (i.e. a stack). Was I mistaken? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as said, the real solution here it to store the array in reverse to how you are doing it presently, which is basically appending items to the end.

As of MongoDB 2.6 and later you can use the [**`$position`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) modifier to basically ["pre-pend"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/#add-elements-at-the-start-of-the-array) items to the array:

```
Story.update(
    { "_id": story_id },
    { "$push": {
        "messages": {
            "$each": elementsAsArray,
            "$position": 0
        }
    }},
    function(err,numAffected) {

   }
);
```

This needs to be called with the [**`$each`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) modifier even when adding a single element.

Otherwise you can apply the [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) modifier, but it does make sense to have something to "sort" on so the elements are in fact ordered. So possibly a "modified" date field:

```
Story.update(
    { "_id": story_id },
    { "$push": {
        "messages": {
            "$each": elementsAsArray,
            "$sort": { "modified": -1 },
            "$slice": 100
        }
    }},
    function(err,numAffected) {

   }
);
```

For versions prior to MongoDB 2.6 the [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/) modifier is required as well, but you can set this to a number larger than the number of elements you expect to be in the array. Or in fact use it in order to "limit" how large the array can possibly get.

You can even note the "tip" on the [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) documentation:

> *"TIP
>   You can pass an empty array [] to the $each modifier such that only the $sort modifier has an effect."*

So that could be used to update existing items in bulk where there is indeed a "sub-field" that is available to sort on.

Once you have this in place, then the [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) operator for projection will function as required. Where `skip` will progress *forwards* through the array and `limit` will restrict the number of items to return.

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful.  My Mongoose version (3.8.15) did not like $position, but I was able to get it working using the second ($sort) method you suggested.  I did change the slice parameter to a negative number (i.e. $slice: -500).  Because the push now uses a sort operator, will the performance be much worse than pushing at the end of the array? My sort is just {_id: 1} to sort by creation date.

Comment: @PraneethWanigasekera Your sort will have to be *negative* in order to have the latest entry first, and that is also the reason to slice from the start of the array and not the end. It is not the Mongooose version that matters but the MongoDB server version. But it still does not alter the main issue in that you cannot "page" backwards from the end of the array. So your best option is to upgrade the servers and the next best is live with the sort. Otherwise if your arrays are actually around 500 entries you are probably better off not embedding and use a referenced model instead.

Comment: Thanks Neil. For some reason positive values for $slice gives me an exception  errmsg: 'exception: $slice value must be negative or zero'.  Full text of the error is: { [OperationalError: exception: $slice value must be negative or zero]
  name: 'OperationalError',
  message: 'exception: $slice value must be negative or zero',
  cause: 
   { [MongoError: exception: $slice value must be negative or zero]
     stack: 'Error: exception: $slice value must be negative or zero\n    at Object.toError (/home/ec2-user/natserver/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/utils.js:114:11)\n..

Comment: @PraneethWanigasekera `skip` and `limit` so `[0,500]`

Comment: The exception happens when inserting into the array, without doing any accesses.    Story.findByIdAndUpdate(story_id, {"$push": {"messages": {
                "$each": [message],
                "$sort": { _id: -1},
                $slice: 500
               } 
               }
}, 
             {safe: true, upsert: true})

Comment: @PraneethWanigasekera Hmm. Mongoose might be broken. Try the native driver object `Story.collection.update()`. Also "safe" is long deprecated. Use the properly defined write concern constants instead, and the default is already "acknowledged" which is what "safe" was an old equivalent for.

Comment: Seems to be another v2.4 vs v2.6 difference.

Comment: Story.collection.update() gives the same error, v2.4 does not support positive $slice values I think.

Comment: I managed to upgrade the db version and the first solution worked.  Note that the second solution did not work on v2.4 (positive values for slice are not allowed by the Native driver through story.collection.update().